# Usar script JavaScript em um component um ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, aplicação-web

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web em react.js e estou precisando rodar um script em js que faz uma busca filtrando automaticamente.

A searchbox é um component do react e preciso rodar um js externo pra que funcione.

component tsx:

```js
function SearchBar() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container-book">
                <input id="searchBar" className='form-control mb-5 p-3' type="text" placeholder="Buscar título..." autoFocus
                    autoComplete='off' />

                <ul id="bookList" className="list-group list-group-flush text-primary"></ul>
            </div>


            <script src="/src/js/search-titles.js"></script>
        </>
    )
}

export default SearchBar
```

Script js:

```js
const bookList = document.getElementById('bookList');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
let booksList = [];

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filteredCharacters = booksList.filter((book) => {
        return (
            book.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
            book.age.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        );
    });
    displayCharacters(filteredCharacters);
});

const loadBooks = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/src/assets/teste.json');
        booksList = await res.json();
        displayCharacters(booksList);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const displayCharacters = (books) => {
    const htmlString = books
        .map((book) => {
            return `
            <li class="book">
                <h2>${book.name}</h2>
                <p>Age: ${book.age}</p>
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    bookList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadBooks();
```

Tudo funciona como deveria se usasse direto no html.

Comment: como assim? demostre? coloque na pergunta!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro que o script não será executado na `React DOM`, isso porque o [Virtual DOM na qual o ReactJS computa a diferença](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), usa a propriedade `innerHTML` para setar o conteúdo do elemento React Element e isso [não vai funcionar por questão de segurança](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#considera%C3%A7%C3%B5es_de_seguran%C3%A7a) (anti-XSS), *e isso também ignora a tentativa de usar o `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`*.

Segundo, para mim, o código do script poderia ser totalmente implementado no component com os hooks `useEffect` e `useCallback`.

---

## Solução:

Agora para importar este script que precisa de um elemento renderizado, você pode do mesmo modo alterar o DOM diretamente com js, inserindo uma tag `<script>` assim que renderizado o component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function SearchBar() {

  // este useEffect será chamado logo ao renderizar o component
  useEffect(() => {
    let head = document.querySelector("head");
    let scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
      
    scriptEl.setAttribute("async", "");
    scriptEl.setAttribute("src", "/src/js/search-titles.js">;
      
    head.appendChild(scriptEl);
      
      return () => { head.removeChild(scriptEl); }
  }, []);

  return (
    ...tsx
  );
}
```

**Inclusive, isto pode ser extraído para um Hook:**

```
export function useScript(sourceUrl) {
  useEffect(() => {
    let head = document.querySelector("head");
    let scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
    
    scriptEl.setAttribute("async", "");
    scriptEl.setAttribute("src", sourceUrl);
    
    head.appendChild(scriptEl);
    
    return () => { head.removeChild(scriptEl); }
  }, []);
}

// no component que será usado o hook
function SearchBar() {
  useScript("/src/nomeScript.js");

  return (
    <>...tsx</>
  );
}
```

---

### Alternativa:

Uma outra solução alternativa seria utilizar o npm package [React-Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet), o qual também permite alterar o `<head>` no component renderizado:

```
function SearchBar() {
 
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <script src="/src/script.js" async />
      </Helmet>
      {/* <>...tsx</> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hmm entendi. Como faço pra inserir o script dentro do próprio component? Realmente acabei de começar em Ts

Comment: @wlnyyyy Pode aplicar o useEffect no corpo da função.. Logo que renderizado ele é executado, e o script vai ser carregado pelo browser.